# Escape '%' while using Oracle's REGEXP_LIKE function

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle

I tied searching on SO about my issue but didn't find one. I apologize if it is a duplicate.

Let's say I have a table as shown below:

```
|ACCOUNT | FEES_DETAILS        |
================================
|AX001   | AOF=£20.5,VAT=25%   |
|AX009   | AOF=11.25%,VAT=12.5%|
```

I want to fetch all the rows when FEES_DETAILS column has a %-based AOF(in the above example, I need to fetch the second record - AX009 as AOF=11.25%).

I am executing the following query but it is not returning any row(s):

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_FEES_DATA WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(FEES_DETAILS, 'AOF\s*=\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%');
```

I thought `%` at the end of my regular expression [`AOF\s*=\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%`](https://regex101.com/r/fPMfUt/1) is being treated as a special character so I tried to escape it with a `\`. But that too didn't return any rows. Is there any other way of escaping a `%` in `REGEXP_LIKE` function?  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Remove `?:` in `(?:...)`

Comment: Is your fees_details have only two values? I.e. AOF and VAT?

Comment: Actually, your query should not be interested in separate parts of the `fees_details`, because if they were of interest, you'd have a `fees_details` table instead with the values already stored in separate rows. So, what you're dealing with here may be a flaw in the database design.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from test where REGEXP_LIKE(fees,'AOF=\d+.\d+%,');
```